# Let X and Y be topological spaces. A function f: X → Y is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}$ (C) is closed in X for every closed set C ⊂ Y.

Tags: general-topology

***I need help proving this theorem***

This is the first part of the biconditional, I think if I can prove this. Proving the converse shouldn't be nearly as difficult.

Assume f is continuous ⇒ $f^{-1}$ (C) is closed in X for every closed set C ⊂ Y.

**Referencing Theorem 4.7,**

Let f: X → Y.  f is continuous at a point x ∈ X iff for each neighborhood M of f(a), $f^{-1}$ (M)  is a neighborhood of a

**Referencing Theorem 6.3,**

Let f: X → Y.  Then f is continuous iff for each open set O of Y, the subset $f^{-1}$ (O) is an open subset of X.

**Referencing Theorem 6.5,**

A subset F of a topological space is said to be closed iff its compliment, C(F), is open.

**Referencing the definition of a continuous function,**

Let X and Y be topological spaces. A function f : X → Y is continuous if, for every x ∈ X and every open set U containing f(x), there exists a neighborhood V of x such that f(V) ⊂ U.

**Proof:**

Let C be a closed subset of Y, s.t, C ⊂ Y. Clearly, if C is closed, the set Y-C  is open since the compliment of a closed set is an open set(Theorem 6.5). Thus, since the inverse image of an open set is open, $f^{-1}$ (C) is open. Notice, that the topological space X can be written as  $f^{-1}$ (Y–C)  ⋃ $f^{-1}$ (C).

Comment: When asking questions like that, you really should *state the definition you're working with*. This is one of the possible definitions of continuity.

Comment: This is the definition of continuity we were instructed to use; Let X and Y be topological spaces. A function f : X → Y is continuous if, for every x ∈ X and every open set U containing f(x), there exists a neighborhood V of x such that f(V) ⊂ U.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $f^{-1}(Y - C) = X - f^{-1}(C) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X.$

Comment: I can see the logic, but this sort of reasoning feels circular to me

Comment: the first equality is completely set theoretic, nothing to do with continuity. now $Y-C$ is open in $Y.$ So $f^{-1}(Y - C)$ is open in $X.$ hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $O \subseteq Y$ be open, we need to show that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, which means exactly that we have to show that $X \setminus f^{-1}[O]$ is closed.

Now, $Y \setminus O$ is closed, so the assumption on $f$ gives us that $f^{-1}[Y \setminus O]$ is closed.

Now set theory in general tells us that $f^{-1}[Y \setminus O] = X \setminus f^{-1}[O]$ ($x$ is in the left hand side iff $f(x) \in Y \setminus O$ and this happens iff $f(x) \notin O$, which is saying exactly that $x \notin f^{-1}[O]$, or $x \in X \setminus f^{-1}[O]$).

Combining these three statements gives us that indeed $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, as required.